# call a bash script from a scala program ( in windows )

Tags: windows, bash, scala, intellij-idea, sh

I have a bash script called test ( I made a simple one just for test )

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Hello world"
```

I tried to call it from a simple scala program in several ways :

```
1 )   "C:\\Users\\me\\project\\myProject\\scripts\\test.bash"!!

and I got this:  error CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

I found in internet that I should add the path for bash.exe because I am in windows
So I made this:

```
val p = Process("C:\\Users\\me\\DevTools\\cmder\\vendor\\git-for-windows\\bin\\bash.exe C:\\Users\\me\\project\\myProject\\scripts\\test.bash")
```

I have no errors ,
but I don't know if it works, In fact I did this

```
print(p.run().toString)
```

It gives an "UNDIFNED"

My question: How to call the script ? and How to manipulate the result: I want to test the output.
Thanks

Comment: Are you able to call the script outside of **Scala**?

Comment: yes from my commander console , it writes " a hello world"

Comment: Have you tried with [os-lib](https://github.com/com-lihaoyi/os-lib)? It is super easy! Perhaps you can solve your problem leveraging this library :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find the solution

> val commandLine: String = " path_to\bash.exe path_to\script.bash"

> val result= Process(commandLine).lineStream

and then you can manipulate your result , for my cases I tested that it should contain an expected string ..